# How do you calculate the effect size of one-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test?

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

Can you / how do you calculate the effect of a one-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test?

Is there a way to perform the calculation in SPSS or another software package?

Comment: In SPSS see the [NPTESTS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Fsyn_nonparametric.htm) procedure to calculate the Wilcoxon signed rank test for a pre-specified median.

Answer (score 3):

The Hodges-Lehmann statistic is the estimator associated with the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.  Form the $n(n+1)/2$ pairwise averages $(x_i + x_j)/2$ for $i \leq j = 1, \dots, n$; take the median; and there you are.

I strongly suspect there's a procedure in SPSS for it, although a quick search of the web didn't turn up anything, and in R there's the exactRankTests package with `wilcox.test` in it, which function has an option that will return both the point estimate and a confidence interval.

Edit: I notice that although exactRankTests is still available, it's not being developed any more and the coin package is recommended instead.  It, too, has `wilcox.test`, and the syntax looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

The Hodges-Lehman estimator is only suitable if your distributions are symmetrical, i.e. not skewed [source p35.](http://store.elsevier.com/Introduction-to-Robust-Estimation-and-Hypothesis-Testing/Rand-Wilcox/isbn-9780123870155/)

Another solution for a non-parametric effect size is z divided by the root of N (r=Z/SQRT(N)) as [others](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133077/effect-size-to-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test) have suggested.

Yet other suggestions are the standardised mean difference or the probability of superiority as described [here](http://psycnet.apa.org/index.cfm?fa=buy.optionToBuy&id=2008-14338-002)

Important is that you check how your data is distributed and your data collection method as each of these solutions have slightly different assumptions.

As for SPSS I don't know because I use R for data manipulation, analysis and visualisation.