# teststatistic vs linearstatistic in wilcoxsign_test

Tags: r, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

In R, `wilcoxsign_test` in library `coin` calculates both a "teststatistic" (output as "Z") and a "linearstatistic" (I think this is either Siegel's (1956) *T* or Glantz' (2005) *W*).

What is "Z", which should I report, and why?

Example:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 11:20
library(coin)
wilcoxsign_test(y ~ x, distribution="exact")
#   Exact Wilcoxon-Signed-Rank Test
# 
# data:  y by x (neg, pos) 
#    stratified by block
# Z = 3.1623, p-value = 0.001953
# alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
wilcoxsign_test(y ~ x, distribution="exact")@statistic@linearstatistic
# [1] 55
wilcoxsign_test(y ~ x, distribution="exact")@statistic@teststatistic
#      neg 
# 3.162278
```

Comment: `coin` [vignettes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coin/index.html) and [JSS article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i08/) provide an answer to your questions.

Comment: @Tim From the information you gave me, is it correct to say that the symbol for "linearstatistic" is "T"?

Comment: Yes, and you can extract those using `statistic(object, "linear")` or `statistic(object, "standardized")`.