# how do I calculate effect size for data based on Wilcoxon signed ranks test

Tags: effect-size

How do I calculate effect size for data based on Wilcoxon signed ranks test. Any step-by-step guidelines? What software should I use?

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  From what I can tell, basically any number crunching software (including excel), and by extension virtually any programming language, should be capable of conducting the test in question.  There seem to be about 2700 walkthroughs available for this type of test based upon a simple internet search.

Comment: If the indicated duplicate (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133077/effect-size-to-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test ) doesn't solve your question, please edit to clearly indicate the precise part of your question it doesn't cover and flag to ask to reopen -- or post a new one that's clearly distinct from that one